# How do I do imports from a python script when my main scripts are in a subfolder of the whole package?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a small folder structure for a project and do not want to complicate things too much. I want to split the components into

- a folder for reusable code for each tool I try
- a folder for main script files, which I can call via python script.py

So my current structure looks like this:

```
project
|
  - tools
  |
    - __init__.py
    - tool_a
    |
      - __init__.py
      - file.py
      - file2.py
  |
   - tool_b
     |
      - __init__.py
|
  - start_scripts
  |
    - start_use_case_1.py
    - start_use_case_2.py
```

Now inside `start_use_case_1.py` I'd like to do an import of the module `tools.tool_a.file`. Following approaches have failed:

```
import tools.tool_a.file
```

and then from folder `project/` call `python start_scripts/start_use_case_1.py`. It cannot find the module `tools`. But when I do the same from an interactive python shell, it works.

The following didn't work either:

```
from ..tools.tool_a import file
```

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I read that it's not allowed to do relative imports from `__main__` scripts. Even though I would not really care for good style, because these startup scripts are the throwaway part of the project. I just do not want to retype them each time in an interpreter.

Comment: You need to add the `tools` directory (package) to `sys.path`

Comment: Actually not the `tools`, but the `project`. This seems to work, but this even works when I set `sys.path.append("./")`. Looking at the output before setting and after setting, it seems `./` is not part of the python path, but the rule to search the current directory for module import is programmed somewhere else (not via the python path).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add path to directory for importing code snippet from any file which can be done like this :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

Now you can do : `from tools import tool_a`